# Primefaces v10 - I need to make a <p:textEditor> unresizable and set a maxlength

Tags: jsf, primefaces, quill

I use Primefaces v10 and I need to make a <p:textEditor> unresizable and set a maxlength..

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you mean with unresizeable. For me the editor is fixed. If you want to apply custom styles to it, please check out [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

About the maximum length, you can add a JSF `validateLength` validator to it:

```html
<p:textEditor ...>
  <f:validateLength maximum="1000" />
</p:textEditor>
```